# WebTestClient with multipart file upload

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I'm building a microservice using Spring Boot + Webflux, and I have an endpoint that accepts a multipart file upload. Which is working fine when I test with curl and Postman

```
@PostMapping("/upload", consumes = [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
fun uploadVideo(@RequestPart("video") filePart: Mono<FilePart>): Mono<UploadResult> {

    log.info("Video upload request received")

    return videoFilePart.flatMap { video ->
        val fileName = video.filename()

        log.info("Saving video to tmp directory: $fileName")

        val file = temporaryFilePath(fileName).toFile()

        video.transferTo(file)
          .thenReturn(UploadResult(true))
          .doOnError { error ->
              log.error("Failed to save video to temporary directory", error)
          }
          .onErrorMap {
              VideoUploadException("Failed to save video to temporary directory")
          }
    }
}
```

I'm now trying to test using WebTestClient:

```
@Test
fun shouldSuccessfullyUploadVideo() {
    client.post()
        .uri("/video/upload")
        .contentType(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .syncBody(generateBody())
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        .is2xxSuccessful
}

private fun generateBody(): MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<*>> {
    val builder = MultipartBodyBuilder()
    builder.part("video", ClassPathResource("/videos/sunset.mp4"))
    return builder.build()
}
```

The endpoint is returning a 500 because I haven't created the temp directory location to write the files to. However the test is passing even though I'm checking for `is2xxSuccessful` if I debug into the assertion that `is2xxSuccessful` performs, I can see it's failing because of the 500, however I'm still getting a green test

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. The `VideoUploadException` that I map to simply extends `ResponseStatusException`

```
class VideoUploadException(reason: String) : ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason)
```

Comment: Did you every figure this out? I'm having a similar issue with webTestClient testing a file upload.

Comment: No, I ended up using https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client instead. We also had issues with web client consuming too much memory